# Why is $i$ here?

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, computer-science, wolfram-alpha

So I was trying to put $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\pi(n)}$$(where $\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function) into Wolfram Alpha. It didn't work. So I decided to replace $\pi(n)$ with $\ln n$. I got [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Cn%5D%2Cln%5C%2840%29n%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bn%2C2%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D). But what's "i" doing here? (I couldn't add LaTeX or the post will look weird). I have no idea why Wolfram Alpha did this. Surely ln n will never be imaginary in the realm of numbers greater than 2, am I right?

[image]

Comment: Approximation error. The imaginary part goes away with more precision (click "more digits")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error estimates for these types of sums are often obtained by relating the sum to an integral which is then evaluated numerically. That introduces numerical error which can produce a very small imaginary portion.

You can enter the prime counting function $\pi(n)$ into WolframAlpha as

```
primepi(n)
```

Thus, the following should estimate your desired sum:

[`sum (-1)^n/primepi(n), n=2..inf`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28-1%29%5En%2Fprimepi%28n%29%2C+n%3D2..inf)

I guess it's pretty easy to see that the answer should be 1 but we again see the numerical error.

Comment: Didn't know that it is actually $1$. Thanks for your answer!