# Solving a contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I am struggling with the following integration,
$$
I = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{i(a+n)(\theta-i\eta)}}{i(\theta -i\eta)}d\theta
$$
where $\eta > 0$, and $i$ is the imaginary symbol, and $a, n$ are constants. The whole integral is similar to a inverse discrete-time Fourier transform of $\frac{e^{ia(\theta-i\eta)}}{i(\theta-i\eta)}$ but with the frequency being a complex number $\kappa = \theta - i\eta$ instead of the real $\theta$.

A similar question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372115/improper-integral-int-0-infty-fraceixx-alpha-dx-convergence).

Can someone give some insights solving this integration?

**Update:** I used mathematica and have a final formula for the integrals now, but not sure how to derive that by hand. Very naturally, by performing variable substitution, I get
$$
I = -i\left( \text{Ei}(-i(n+a)(\pi+i\eta)) - \text{Ei}(i(n+a)(\pi-i\eta)) \right)
$$
where $\text{Ei}(x) = \int_x^{\infty}t^{-1}e^{-t}dt$. ***But this is not correct!***

Comment: @Aruralreader Oops ... I had thought the integral extended over the reals, not on $[-\pi,\pi]$.  I'll delete

Comment: I'm not sure if what I'm saying is crazy, but could $\text d(wh)=w\text d h+h\text d w$ be possible?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Here h is a constant, so $d(\omega h) = hd\omega$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\frac{d}{dh} I(h)$ to obtain (let $a+n=\gamma)$
$$I'(h) =\gamma \,e^{\gamma h\eta}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i\gamma\omega h} d\omega=2\gamma \,e^{\gamma h\eta}\frac{\sin(\pi\gamma h)}{\gamma h}$$
for $\gamma h\neq 0$.
Let me assume that $\gamma >0$. Then, $I(-\infty)=0$ and
$$I(t) =\int_{-\infty}^t 2\gamma \,e^{\gamma h\eta}\frac{\sin(\pi\gamma h)}{\gamma h}\,dh.$$
This may not be what you're looking for, but it is another integral representation which may help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=i(a+n)(\theta-i\eta)$. We get that $$I=-i\int_{i(a+n)(-\pi-i\eta)}^{i(a+n)(\pi-i\eta)}\frac{e^u}udu$$Splitting this integral into two parts, we get that $I=-i(\text{Ei}(i(a+n)(\pi-i\eta))-\text{Ei}(i(a+n)(-\pi-i\eta)))$. You probably forgot the $i$ in the inputs of the exponential integral.

Comment: This is also the result I got! However, it is not the correct result as I mentioned in the post. The final result should also add a step function as another component.

Comment: What makes you think that there should be a step function as the answer? Maybe the context of your problem is incorrect. The integrand is holomorphic so I don’t see how a step function will be involved.

Comment: I put the integration into Mathematica and got the final solution. There should be a step function. But I cannot reproduce their result

Comment: Why are you trusting it blindly? See this for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612318/why-is-i-here That step function could be made from an approximation error or something like that. But there is no way a step function is involved in such an integral.

Comment: Sorry but I am expecting a step function to appear, and I think it has something to do with the sign of (a+n)